# Map System.Uri using Entity Framework Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

Pretty simple question.  I have a model that has a property which is a `System.Uri` type.  `Uri`s don't have a default parameterless constructor, and no ID field.  Is there any way to override my model generation to store it in the DB in a custom way (e.g. just as a `string`)? In NHibernate, I've done this before by implementing `IUserType`, but I could not find yet a similar mechanism in CodeFirst.

Obviously, I could create a custom type that uses a `Uri` under the hood and exposes regular mappable properties & constructor, I'm just curious if there's any way to map this system type so that I don't have to make a wrapper like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF does not support custom type mappings like NH.

For System.Uri in particular, I'd use a wrapper property and map the actual value as a string; it's not that bad.

Comment: Yeah, what I ended up doing was just using a String and then doing a DataType validation attribute.

Comment: I think they got support in 6, not 5.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a code snippet for clarification?

Answer (score 34):

This is a very old question but I just had the same question today. With Entity Framework Core 2.1, you can set up a [Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions):

```
public class MyEntityDbConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.UriField)
                .HasConversion(v => v.ToString(), v => new Uri(v));
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MyEntityDbConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to map `System.Uri` to `string` with EF.

You could however use Data Annotations and attribute your URL property as follows:

```
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
public string Link { get; set; }
```

This will able to tell some services that this should be displayed and validated as a URL (ASP.NET and Silverlight for instance have built in support for it).

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this..

```
[Column(Name="MyUri", TypeName="string")]
public Uri MyUri
```

Make sure you add reference needed for Column Attribute

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I am referring to CTP5 of EF Code First

Comment: No joy,  this did not work. I still get the "Entity would not round-trip" error.