# Entity Framework Core 2.1.1 Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.1

This is my scenario to understand my problem.

In my project I reference the followings:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design 1.1.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.1

My code is:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Uri Address { get; set; }
}

internal class DbManager : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>
{
    public DataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("[My connection string]");
        return new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasKey(a => a.Id).HasName($"{nameof(Foo)}_key");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Partners");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Now, if I run in Package Manager Console, the command `Add-Migration test1`, I obtain the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for
>   entity type 'Uri'. The following parameters could not be bound to
>   properties of the entity: 'uriString', 'uriString', 'dontEscape',
>   'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'dontEscape', 'uriString', 'uriKind',
>   'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'serializationInfo', 'streamingContext',
>   'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'flags', 'uriParser', 'uri'.
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConstructorBindingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)
>        at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>        at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>        at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
>   factory)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
>   contextType)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action)   No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Uri'. The
>   following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity:
>   'uriString', 'uriString', 'dontEscape', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri',
>   'dontEscape', 'uriString', 'uriKind', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri',
>   'serializationInfo', 'streamingContext', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri',
>   'flags', 'uriParser', 'uri'.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Please coin a more descriptive title.

Comment: @GertArnold you are right, it's a duplication question... How can I remove this one?

Comment: No need to remove it. Your question now serves as a signpost to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

System.Uri isn't a supported type which can be mapped by EF. You'll need to provide EF with mapping details in your implementation or you could consider using a string.

There are already some good suggestions in this post: [Map System.Uri using Entity Framework Fluent Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037022/map-system-uri-using-entity-framework-fluent-api)